# Running Cocoapods "pod install" Causes Libraries to Disappear

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, libraries

We are having a problem with an existing project. Running `pod install` causes our existing Pods to break.

Our existing project looks like this:
[image]

After I run `pod install`, several of the libraries that appear in the `Products` directory and under the `Targets` are gone, and the app won't compile:
[image]

Here is the output from `pod install --verbose`

```
myapp-Macbook-Air:myapp username$ pod install --verbose
  Preparing

Updating local specs repositories

Updating spec repo `master`
  $ /usr/bin/git pull --ff-only
  Already up-to-date.

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods`:
  (`$(ARCHS_STANDARD)`)

Finding Podfile changes
  - Dropbox-iOS-SDK
  - FiksuSDK
  - GoogleAnalytics
  - Localytics
  - MobileAppTracker
  - SDWebImage

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`

Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
  - Dropbox-iOS-SDK
  - FiksuSDK
  - GoogleAnalytics
  - Localytics
  - MobileAppTracker
  - SDWebImage

Downloading dependencies

-> Using Dropbox-iOS-SDK (1.3.13)

-> Using FiksuSDK (4.4.1)

-> Using GoogleAnalytics (3.13.0)

-> Using Localytics (3.5.0)

-> Using MobileAppTracker (3.7)

-> Using SDWebImage (3.7.2)
  - Running pre install hooks

Generating Pods project
  - Creating Pods project
  - Adding source files to Pods project
  - Adding frameworks to Pods project
  - Adding libraries to Pods project
  - Adding resources to Pods project
  - Linking headers
  - Installing targets
    - Installing target `SDWebImage` iOS 7.0
    - Installing target `Pods` iOS 7.0
  - Running post install hooks
  - Writing Xcode project file to `Pods/Pods.xcodeproj`
    - Generating deterministic UUIDs
  - Writing Lockfile in `Podfile.lock`
  - Writing Manifest in `Pods/Manifest.lock`

Integrating client project

Integrating target `Pods` (`myapp.xcodeproj` project)
  Adding Build Phase 'Embed Pods Frameworks' to project.
  - Running post install hooks
    - cocoapods-stats from
    `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cocoapods-stats-0.6.2/lib/cocoapods_plugin.rb`

Sending stats
      - Dropbox-iOS-SDK, 1.3.13
      - FiksuSDK, 4.4.1
      - GoogleAnalytics, 3.13.0
      - Localytics, 3.5.0
      - MobileAppTracker, 3.7
      - SDWebImage, 3.7.2
  Pod installation complete! There are 6 dependencies from the Podfile and 6
  total pods installed.

[!] The `myapp [Debug]` target overrides the `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

(We've always had that `GCC_PREPROCESSOR` warning)

Any ideas about what be happening here, would be appreciated.

Some other notes: We are having this problem on Xcode 6 and Xcode 7, but both machines are running OS X 10.11, which might be the problem. Cocoapods v0.39.0. Also tried downgrading to Cocoapods v0.25.0 but the same problem occurs.

Comment: Have you tried running it a second time?

Comment: I have run several times, uninstalled, re-installed ... updated Cocoapods, etc.

Comment: Does the `--verbose` flag give you any useful info?

Comment: Added the `--verbose` output to the original post. Nothing obvious, but I don't know the details about what should or should not be in this output.

Comment: The GCC_PREPROCESSOR warning might suggest pods are being blocked from installing? Have you added new pods or updated versions since doing this? Or, maybe you can update pod versions.

Comment: Hi. Check your project settings for `Debug` configuration. And then `Use the $(inherited) flag, or Remove the build settings from the target.`

Comment: try these steps http://stackoverflow.com/a/37341045/3472073